# WPF Empty Row in ItemsControl Binding with ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have ItemsControl Binding to an ObservableCollection, every thing is ok except when ObservableCollection is empty, the ItemsControl will show one empty row !!

```
<ItemsControl  Visibility="Visible" ItemsSource="{Binding ocItemsinInvoice,Mode=TwoWay}" 
  x:Name="test" Margin="10,-32,0,207" Width="412" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button x:Name="btnOpenInvoice" Style="{StaticResource OpenInvoicesButton}" 
              FontSize="12" Width="300" Height="60" Foreground="#ff252526">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item.ItemName}" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

How can I remove it?

Comment: Post code for your `ItemsControl` template here.

Comment: Are you sure that collection contains no item. I see no issue in your xaml code and i tested it with dummy collection, nothing is shown.

Comment: I'm sure, in page loaded I initialize new instance from ocItemsinInvoice, and when I add new Item add it to ocItemsinInvoice

Comment: What do yo mean exactly by empty row? A Button with no content is shown?

Comment: Yes exactly that is what I mean

Comment: your code doesn't show a button when the collection is empty ... 
The only thing that puzzles me is : `Text="{Binding Item.ItemName}"` What's that item?

Comment: @YoMo - No one will be able to help you out until you provide a psuedo-code replicating your problem.

Comment: try one way binding `ItemsSource="{Binding ocItemsinInvoice, Mode=OneWay}"`

Answer (score 0):

```
public ObservableCollection<object> bindedObservableCollection
{
    get{
        ObservableCollection<object> newlist = new ObservableCollection<object>(yourObservableCollection);
        return newlist;
    }
}
```

I had this issue when binding to a list that was part of a datagrid, I found casting it to a new list of same type removed the blank editors record that is part of the datagrid.